# bipartite graph and size of partitions

Tags: graph-theory

Given a finite graph $G$ which is bipartite with partitions $A$ and $B$ and has no vertices without edges.
For any neighbouring $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$ it holds that $\operatorname{deg} x \geq \operatorname{deg} y$.

How to show, that $|X| \leq |Y|$? (equality, when $\operatorname{deg} x = \operatorname{deg} y$ for all neighbouring $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$).

It certaily holds, that $\sum_x \operatorname{deg} x = \sum_y \operatorname{deg} y$. But I lack a idea to formally derive the statement about the cardinalities of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Do you mean no vertices without edges? You say "has no edges without vertices," and this is true by definition of an edge.

Comment: @ml0105 Thanks, you were right. Corrected.

Comment: Also, I think you need more assumptions. If I take $X = \{v_{1}, v_{2}\}$, $Y = \{v_{3}, v_{4}, v_{5}, v_{6}\}$; and then $E = \{ \{v_{1}, v_{3}\}, \{v_{1}, v_{4}\}, \{v_{2}, v_{5}\}, \{v_{2}, v_{6}\} \}$. Then each vertex in $X$ has degree two and each vertex in $Y$ has degree $1$. However, $Y$ has more vertices than $X$.

Comment: @ml0105 Thanks again. Stupid me, stupid typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

(I expect this statement must have a shorter and more elegant proof, but I was unable to come up with one.)

We use induction on the maximum degree $k$ of the graph.

Induction base: $k=1$.
Since there are no isolated vertices every vertex has degree exactly 1, so the edges
form a perfect matching and $|X|=|Y|$.

Induction step: We assume $k>1$ and the statement proven for all
graphs with smaller maximum degree. Now assume that $G$ is the smallest graph with
maximum degree $k$ for which the statement is false.
Let $P$ be the subset of $X$ containing the vertices of degree $k$
and $Q$ the subset of $Y$ containing the vertices of degree $k$.

$P$ cannot be empty or $Q$ would have to be empty as well and we do not have maximum degree $k$.
If $Q$ would be empty, then we can remove one edge from some vertex in $P$.
This leads to a smaller graph $G'$ with bipartition $X,Y'$, where $Y'$ is either equal to $Y$
or has one element less.
The degree requirement is still satisfied in $G'$, so $|X|\leq|Y'|\leq|Y|$. Contradiction.
So $Q$ is not empty either.

Each vertex of $Q$ has $k$ edges and they all must go to vertices of $P$.
Furthermore each vertex of $P$ can only accomodate only $k$ edges.
This means that the marriage condition (or "Hall's condition") for $Q$ is fulfilled
in the $P,Q$-subgraph, so there is a matching of $Q$.

Now remove the edges of this matching and again you find a smaller graph still satisfying the degree condition
proving that $|X|\leq|Y|$ after all. This final contradiction proves the statement.

Comment: "Each vertex of Q has k edges and they all must go to vertices of P" Why they should go to vertices of P? They can have different neighbors.

Comment: They must go to vertices of degree $\geq k$. These are all in $P$.

Comment: Why they must go to vertices of degree $\ge k$? This was exactly my previous question, and this is your definition for $Q$ : " the subset of Y containing the vertices of degree k", nothing more, and in other line of your proof, you didn't prove the aforementioned claim.

Comment: @Saeed: if $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ and $xy$ is an edge then our requirement asks $d(x)\geq d(y)$. If $y$ is in $Q$, then $d(y)=k$, so the other end of the edge must have a degree at least $k$.

Comment: Aah I see, my mistake you are right.